# MySQL connection doesn't work with HikariCP

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, hikaricp

HikariCP version: 2.6.1
JDK version     : 1.8.0_111
Database        : MySQL
Driver version  : 5.1.6

---

This is my code:

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase");
config.setUsername("root");
config.setPassword("root");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
System.out.println("Hikari datasource: " + config.getDataSource());

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?"
        + "user=root&password=root");
System.out.println("Conn: " + conn);
String select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND enable = 'Y'";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(select);
ps.setString(1, "myemail@gmail.com");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
System.out.println(rs.next());
```

The line `System.out.println( "Hikari datasource: " + config.getDataSource() );` returns null and the line `System.out.println( rs.next() );` returns true.

In other words, Hikari connection is not working for some reason. I also can connect using Wildfly Datasource.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

The method `HikariConfig.getDataSource()` does not do what you think it does. It doesn't provide you with a Hikari `DataSource`, it returns the (non-pooling) data source you have set yourself (if any); which you haven't done in your code, so it returns `null`.

As specified in the [documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#infrequently-used):

> `dataSource`
>   This property is only available via programmatic configuration or IoC container. This property allows you to directly set the instance of the `DataSource` to be wrapped by the pool, rather than having HikariCP construct it via reflection. This can be useful in some dependency injection frameworks. When this property is specified, the `dataSourceClassName` property and all DataSource-specific properties will be ignored. *Default: none*

To create the Hikari data source, you need to use:

```
HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

Then you should **not** use `DriverManager` to get the connection, but the data source instead:

```
ds.getConnection()
```

See also [the initialization example on the HikariCP page](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#initialization).

Also: make sure you close your connections properly (which returns the connection to the pool), your current code doesn't do that. The easiest thing (in Java 7 or higher), is to use try-with-resources:

```
try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection()) {
    // use conn...
}
// conn will have been automatically closed (returned to the pool)
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your time. Your solution worked very well.

Just to register a note, I also had to add
`config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "mydatabase");` to be able to connect to the database, otherwise I was getting `No selected database exception`...

Comment: @LeandroBortolotto I would not expect that if you specified the database in the URL as well, but I don't usually use MySQL, although if you use driver 5.1.6, you might want to consider updating (5.1.6 is  9+ years old), the latest version is 5.1.42